# Does duplicating monitors lower frame rate?

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card

If I was to duplicate my monitor with another, will I lose frame rate when I play games?

By duplicating, I mean going into display settings, and duplicating – not extending – Monitor 1 on Monitor 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Duplicating has no effect on the process of generating the data to be displayed in the frames, so its speed is not affected.

Comment: That's what I figured, just kind of wanted to make sure, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It does affect your framerate.
If your secondary screen cannot produce the same hertz as your primary, or you have a different non-scaling resolution on the other monitor, you will experience a less comfy gameplay. (Non-scaling res; Your primary monitor is at 1920x1080 and your other one is at 800x600 then your graphics card will have to produce 2 different frames to put to show. Cuz it has to render a high res and then also a low res)

In games- everything that takes an extra process, it will affect the game. And all these tiny additions will make it harder for the cpu/gpu to produce the next picture.

In pro games- Every frame counts. Mouse inputs is dependant on the amount of frames produced every second. If you produce 1 frame per second then that's 1 input per second. Meaning you can only send one inpout from your mouse (moved 0.01mm = X amount of pixels moved on the screen(really really bad))

TL;DR
Use one monitor when playing games for smooth gameplay
Using more than one when doing other things is ok.